# Methods of Data Storage - Opinion

Tags: java, android, database, file-io, persistence

I have been working on an app and have encountered some limitations relating to my lack of experience in Java IO and data persistence. Basically I need to store information on a few `Spinner` objects. So far I have saved information on each `Spinner` into a text file using the format of:

```
//Blank Line

Name //the first drop-down entry of the spinner

Type //an enum value

Entries //a semicolon-separated list of the drop-down entry String values

//Blank line
```

And then, assuming this rigid syntax is followed always, I've extracted this information from the saved `.txt` whenever the app is started. But things such as editing these entries and working with certain aspects of the `Scanner` have been an absolute nightmare. If anything is off by even *one* line or space of blankness BAM! everything is ruined. There must be a better way to store information for easy access, something with some search-eability, something that won't be erased the moment the app closes and that isn't completely laxed in its layout to the extent that the most minor of changes destroys everything.

Any recommendations for how to save a simple `String`, a simple `int`, and an array of `String` outside the app? I am looking for a recommendation from an experienced developer here. I have seen the storage options, but am unsure which would be best for just a few simple things. Everything I need could be represented in a 3 X n table wherein n is the number of spinners.

Comment: Android [Data Storage Options article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: `SharedPreferences` might suit your need.

Comment: For your case, sounds like Androids SQLite databasing functionality. There are a few good articles, just a quick Google: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
This of course is assuming that you are trying to save multiple values into the database to be read. If you are hoping to update/replace the values each time a simple SharedPreferences implementation should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your requirements are so minimal, I think the shared preferences approach is probably the best option. If your requirements were more complicated, then a using a database would start to make more sense.

Using shared preferences for simple data like yours really is as simple as the example shown on the [storage options page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: For something more complex would a database allow the removal of entries too?

Comment: Yes, you can add/delete/change entries easily with a database. But you can do the same operations on shared preferences too.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've read the docs on SharedPreferences and have found them so useful, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, to remove shared preferences, use 'editor.commit("setting_to_be_removed");' (assuming 'editor' is the name of the SharedPreferences.Editor you created.)